# Iterating over a Javascript array to calculate a bowling score

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a bowling scoring app and am struggling to calculate my strike score. If a player scores a strike, they get the points for that roll (10) plus the points for the next two rolls. I am trying to work out how to iterate over my array to add the result of the next two rolls. For example, my array of scores might be:

```
scores = [10, 1, 5, 1, 2, 10, 5, 2, 10, 10, 8, 1, 10, 3, 2]
```

I am trying to iterate over the array so that for each time the score is 10, add the next two numbers to the total. I have this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if(scores[i] == 10){
    result += scores[i + 2]
    }
  return result
}
```

This doesn't work. I am VERY new to Javascript!

P.S. I know that a real bowling game has a tenth frame bonus but I am yet to implement that feature.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't really bowl much, but shouldn't you increment the index to prevent counting the two rolls after the strike twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function totalScore(ScoreArray) {
    let result = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        if (scores[i] == 10) {
            result += scores[i + 2] + scores[i + 1];
        }
        result += scores[i];
    }
    return result;
}


totalScore([1, 5, 10, 3, 2]);
```

Though you need extra check also, which you can do on your own.

**Hint:** Ensure the next 2 values exist in array. Then only add it to `result`. This function will throw error in case last value is 10.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store `result` outside of your loop

```
let result = 0;

for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  if (score[i] === 10) {
    result += scores[i + 1];
    result += scores[i + 2];
  }

  result += score[i];
}
```

Or with a more functional approach:

```
function calculateScore(scores) {
  let result = 0;

  scores.forEach((score, index) => {
    if (score === 10) {
      result += scores[index + 1];
      result += scores[index + 2];
    }

    result += score;
  });

  return result;
}
```

And using `Array.reduce()`

```
function calculateScore(scores) {
  return scores.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
    if (currentValue === 10) {
      return accumulator + currentValue + scores[index + 1] + scores[index + 2];
    }

    return accumulator + currentValue;
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: OP is not redeclaring `result` in the loop. He just doesn't show where it is declared.

Answer (score -1):

```
let result = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  if (scores[i] === 10) {
    result += (i + 1 < scores.length) ? scores[i + 1] : 0;
    result += (i + 2 < scores.length) ? scores[i + 2] : 0;
  }
  result += scores[i];
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!